# How do I call properties from one class into a different class? c# (noob level)

Tags: c#, class, properties

I have a business logic class `historyBL` that has the `FindCustomer()` method that takes the `clientID` property. In a method from a different bl class (let's say `exchangeBL`) i have a method in which I need to call the `FindCustomer()` method (from the other BL class).

i will write `historyBl.FindCustomer(clientID)` but it will say clientID is not in this context.

How do I bring it here?

Comment: You can send a reference to your class as a argument of the other function; if your class is already defined in VS20XX, it will be available in your assembly unless it is not public. One of the arguments of `FindCustomer()` would be of type (your class) historyBL, e.g. `void YourMethod(historyBL hbl) { hbl.FindCustomer(); }`

Comment: Bear in mind there are multiple ways of sorting this out from a simple one like I have provided to more advanced uing DI. Unless you provide more information, it is impossible to provide specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to call the following, the clientID must be a local variable in the scope of the calling function:

```
historyBL myHistoryBLObject = new historyBL();
int clientID = 42;
myHistoryBLObject.FindCustomer(clientID);
```